# Basic Questions on Elliptic Complex

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

The questions are from Atiyah, Hitchin and Singer's paper Self-duality in four dimensional Riemannian geometry.

Assume $P$ is a principal $G$ bundle over $X$, $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. Here is a complex $$0 \longrightarrow A^0(\mathfrak{g}) \stackrel{d_0}{\longrightarrow} A^1(\mathfrak{g}) \stackrel{d_1}{\longrightarrow} A^2_{-}(\mathfrak{g}) \longrightarrow 0,$$  $d_0=\nabla$ is the covariant derivative and $d_1=p_{-}D_1$, which is the projection of the two form gotten from the extended covariant derivative to its anti self dual part. My first question is how to calculate it's symbol to check it's an elliptic complex?

It is needed to prove $h^2$ of the complex is vanishing. And why it can be replaced by a single elliptic operator $d+d^{*}:A^1(\mathfrak{g}) \longrightarrow A^0(\mathfrak{g}) \oplus A^2(\mathfrak{g})$. And what's the relation between the index of this operator and $h^2$? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not appropriate for MO, but you can try http://math.stackexchange.com/ or textbooks such as **Geometry of Four-Manifolds** (Donaldson-Kronheimer) or **Spin Geometry** (Lawson-Michelson).